# check if array contains string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to write a code that will create a file with an amount of random jokes using [this npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/one-liner-joke) and Environment Variables in an env file but I can't get it to work.

here is the code:

```
let oneLinerJoke = require("one-liner-joke");

require("dotenv").config();

let fs = require("fs");

var getRandomJokeWithTag = oneLinerJoke.getRandomJokeWithTag(
  `${process.env.JOKE_SUBJECT}`
);

let arrayJokes = [];

let i = 0;

let counter = 0;

let amount = parseInt(`${process.env.JOKE_AMOUNT}`);

while (i <= amount) {

    let joke = oneLinerJoke.getRandomJokeWithTag(process.env.JOKE_SUBJECT);

    joke = joke.body.replace(",", "");

    if (arrayJokes.includes(joke)) {

        arrayJokes.push((joke + "\n"));

        i++;

    }
}

const createFile = fs.writeFileSync('./created_files/jokes.txt', arrayJokes.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add __dirname to specify the directory.

```
const createFile = fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/created_files/jokes.txt', arrayJokes.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).